# Does German have an equivalent of "love" in the context of tennis?

Tags: noun

What would be the term used in a no score situation, or if there's a new game?

Comment: Can you explain the phenomenon a bit more in detail? I think that would help answer your question.

Comment: No, we just use “null” (zero).

Comment: I don't understand the question. What *is* the meaning of "love" in the context of tennis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, German has no such specific expression.

Points in Tennis are scored just like in any other sports:

> Es steht Fünfzehn zu Null im Davis-Cup-Endspiel

or, for a short announcement:

> Null - Fünfzehn!